# How to paginate using ONLY JSTL c:ForEach without javascript or jquery?

Tags: jsp, pagination, jstl

I hear it's possible to paginate using JSTL **only**. I have seen and tried many code samples which did not give any good result. I have tried this code [here](http://jstl-code.blogspot.ca/2011/05/jstl-pagination.html) which returned a blank page. So far the code below is what I have and it is working but how do I display NEXT and PREVIOUS?

```
<c:forEach var="product" items="${categoryProducts}" begin="1" end="8" varStatus="iter">
<div class="product_container">

    <div class="product_img">
        <a href="viewProduct?${product.id}">    <img class="product_picture" alt="" src="${initParam.productGalleryImagePath}${product.id} (1).jpg" /></a>
    </div>


    <div class="product_name">
        <a href="viewProduct?${product.id}">${product.name}</a>
    </div>


    <div class="product_price">

        <a href="viewProduct?${product.id}">$${product.price}</a>

    </div>

</div>
</c:forEach>

<div class="pagination">
     <c:if test="${product.start > 1}">
 NEXT
</c:if>
<c:if test="${product.end} < ${fn:length(product)}">
 PREVIOUS
</c:if>
</div>
```

rickz code:

```
   <c:set var="product" scope="session" value="${categoryProducts}"/>
<c:set var="totalCount" scope="session" value="${categoryProducts}"/>
<c:set var="perPage" scope="session"  value="10"/>
<c:set var="pageStart" value="${param.start}"/>
<c:if test="${empty pageStart or pageStart < 0}">
       <c:set var="pageStart" value="0"/>
</c:if>
<c:if test="${totalCount < pageStart}">
       <c:set var="pageStart" value="${pageStart - 10}"/>
</c:if>
    <a href="category.jsp?start=${pageStart - 10}">Previous</a>${pageStart + 1} - ${pageStart + 10} 
    <a href="category.jsp?start=${pageStart + 10}">Next</a>
```

Comment: how many products do you want to show per page?

Comment: @PaulNgom: 24 products per page.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a demonstration.

```
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%> 
<%
   List<String> letters = Arrays.asList("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z");
%>
<c:set var="letters" scope="session" value="<%=letters%>"/>
<c:set var="totalCount" scope="session" value="<%=letters.size()%>"/>
<c:set var="perPage" scope="session"  value="10"/>
<c:set var="pageStart" value="${param.start}"/>
<c:if test="${empty pageStart or pageStart < 0}">
       <c:set var="pageStart" value="0"/>
</c:if>
<c:if test="${totalCount < pageStart}">
       <c:set var="pageStart" value="${pageStart - 10}"/>
</c:if>
    <a href="?start=${pageStart - 10}"><<</a>${pageStart + 1} - ${pageStart + 10} 
    <a href="?start=${pageStart + 10}">>></a>                                               
<h1>Letters</h1>
   <c:forEach var="letter" items="${letters}" varStatus="letterCounter"
                        begin="${pageStart}" end="${pageStart + perPage - 1}">
              ${letter}
   </c:forEach>
```

EDIT:

What type of object is categoryProducts?
You need to find its size. You could try adding

```
<%@ taglib prefix = "fn" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
```

and try using

```
<c:set var="totalCount" scope="session" value="${fn:length(categoryProducts)}"/>
```

EDIT2:

```
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%> 
<%
   List<String> letters = Arrays.asList("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z");
%>
<c:set var="letters" scope="session" value="<%=letters%>"/>
<c:set var="totalCount" scope="session" value="<%=letters.size()%>"/>
<c:set var="perPage" scope="session"  value="${5}"/>
<c:set var="pageStart" value="${param.start}"/>
<c:if test="${empty pageStart or pageStart < 0}">
       <c:set var="pageStart" value="0"/>
</c:if>
<c:if test="${totalCount < pageStart}">
       <c:set var="pageStart" value="${pageStart - perPage}"/>
</c:if>
    <a href="?start=${pageStart - perPage}"><<</a>${pageStart + 1} - ${pageStart + perPage} 
    <a href="?start=${pageStart + perPage}">>></a>                                               
<h1>Letters</h1>
   <c:forEach var="letter" items="${letters}" 
                        begin="${pageStart}" end="${pageStart + perPage - 1}">
              ${letter}
   </c:forEach>
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Beginner question: why do you call `arrays`? I thought it was the exact purpose of the `for each`?

Comment: I used the Arrays class(and it's static method asList) to create my list. I needed something to demonstrate my code. You don't need to use it because you already have categoryProducts.

Comment: I tried your code just now. It works except for the links. When I click on "next" or "previous" I receive this error: `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "start=10"`

Comment: The code that I posted works for me. Did you copy and paste into a jsp file on your server? If you wrote new code, then please post it.

Comment: @Please see the update for your code adapted to mine. Do you see any problem in what I did?

Comment: Please see my edit in my answer for my suggestion as to how to correct your code.. Also, did you copy and paste my code to test on your server? Did it work?

Comment: Yes. I pasted your code to my server. And added your edit. It compiles and displays in the browser. However, the code does not take effect on the number of products displayed per page. Say if I change `<c:set var="perPage" scope="session"  value="10"/>` for `<c:set var="perPage" scope="session"  value="5"/>` it does not take effect. The number of products per page still remain the same.

Comment: I cleaned up my code in my EDIT2 in my answer. Now you can change the value of the perPage variable. I got rid of the hardcoded values of 10.

Comment: Dude, my bad I forgot to modify this `<c:forEach var="product" items="${categoryProducts}" begin="1" end="8" varStatus="iter">` for this `<c:forEach var="product" items="${categoryProducts}" begin="${pageStart}" end="${pageStart + perPage - 1}" varStatus="iter">`. Now the value perPage works great. Thanks. The only issue now is still with the links. When clicking on preview or next, I get this error `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "start=5"`

Comment: You will have to post code that will demonstrate the error. Use the list of letters like I did in my answer. That way we can run your code and reproduce the error.

Comment: The code in the question is what I use. Please look above. There's nothing else. Searching for a solution I have found this: A Java NumberFormatException usually occurs when we try to do something like convert a String to a numeric value, like an int, float, double, long, etc... Isn't it what we're trying to do? How to get around this? I don't need to use arrays, it will be way too long. I will keep looking for solutions.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. Maybe the error message is a clue; For input string: "start=5"  I don't know what input that is referring to but the input probably should be just "5".  Do you know what line is causing the error?

Comment: Maybe this edit will help you. <c:set var="perPage" scope="session"  value="${5}"/>  But it worked for me before that change.

Comment: Hey mate! Thanks for your reply! Yes it was working without `<c:set var="perPage" scope="session" value="${5}"/>`. This is not the issue. The problem is that it cant find `<a href="?start=${pageStart - perPage}"><<</a>` `${pageStart + 1} - ${pageStart + perPage} 
    <a href="?start=${pageStart + perPage}">>></a>` It returns a 404 not found page. So i'm guessing I have to make another page so it can send the data over there? I think the guy below as it right.

Comment: I thought you were using <a href="category.jsp?start=${pageStart - perPage}">Previous</a>   didn't that work?

Comment: No matter what I try it cannot find the links `:/` I think the issue stands from   me not using arrays... I'm using classes and a servlet.

Comment: No, that can't be the reason. Here is another way to try  <a href="${pageContext.request.servletPath}?start=${pageStart - perPage}"><<</a>

Comment: Thanks again for your reply rickz. I tried your new snippet and it gives same 404 result. It cannot find the page... If the code works for you and you're using arrays and I'm not, something tells me that is the issue... Would you mind doing tests with your code using c:forEach instead of arrays and see if it still works?

Comment: The type of collection for the forEach doesn't effect the links. Please show us the source code that the server sent the browser for that last snippet that I posted. There has to be a simple explanation. Also, try  <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}${pageContext.request.servletPath}?start=${pageStart - perPage}"><<</a>

Comment: If that last code doesn't work, then post the source code that the server sent to the browser for it

Comment: Thanks again rickz. I tried your last code and no it does not work either. Same 404. So I decided to go back to: `<a href="category.jsp?start=${pageStart - 12}">` and `<a href="category.jsp?start=${pageStart + 12}">` What do you mean when you say source code that the server sent to browser for it?

Comment: Source code is what the server sent to browser. To see it in IE browser right-click on background and choose "View source" in popup menu.

Answer (score 2):

See if this can help. You call the page like this:

**pagination.jsp?start=1&end=72**

pagination.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.0//EN" "http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/xhtml-mobile10.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head><title>pagination</title>
<body>
<c:set var="count" value="${0}" scope="page" />
<c:set var="start" value="${0}" scope="page" />
<c:set var="startcount" value="${param.start}" scope="page" />

<c:set var="endcount" value="${param.end}" scope="page" />
<c:set var="allend" value="${72}" scope="page" />
<c:set var="stepcount" value="${1}" scope="page" />

<c:if test="${endcount>allend}">
 <c:set var="endcount" value="${allend}" scope="page" />
</c:if>
<c:forEach var="counter" begin="${startcount}" end="${endcount}" step="${stepcount}">
 <c:if test="${count < 24}">
  ${counter}<br/>
 <c:set var="count" value="${count + 1}" scope="page" />
 <c:set var="end" value="${counter+count-1}" scope="page" />
 <c:set var="start" value="${counter}" scope="page" />
 </c:if>
</c:forEach>
<c:if test="${endcount>allend}">
 <c:set var="start" value="${1}" scope="page" />
 <c:set var="end" value="${allend}" scope="page" />
</c:if>


<c:if test="${endcount!=allend}">
<a href="pagination.jsp?start=${(count==1)?1:start}&end=${end}">NEXT</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</c:if>
<c:if test="${startcount>24-1}">
 <a href="pagination.jsp?start=${startcount-24+1}&end=${startcount}">PREVIOUS</a>
</c:if>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Beginner question: When you say you call the page, what do you mean? I need to create another jsp?

Comment: You do not need to create another jsp. You just copy and save the code under the name pagination.jsp and copy the file to your server. Then you can display it from a browser. Do not forget to append pagination.jsp?start=1&end=72 to the address

Comment: I tried and adapted your code just now (see the edit) and for strange reason, there's only one product displaying now and when I click on links I get 404 error `:/`